# check if java process is running and re-run if it is not running

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

On ubuntu 15.04, I am running java app through vnc sessions.  I have 8 defined sessions that are started during system boot.  My question is, how do I create a script that checks to see if the process is still running on the various vnc displays (say :1 to :8) and re-start the java process if I detect a given vnc session is not running?

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted at Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816928/check-if-java-process-is-running-and-re-run-if-it-is-not-running

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 15.04 has systemd for this kind of needs.

The following is an example of .service file you need to write for you application

```
[Unit]
Description=Some kind of description

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=<path to your bin with args if needed>
Restart=on-failure
```

Save this file with name `<your-app-name>.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/` and run the following to start it

```
sudo systemctl start <your-app-name>
```

If you want it to run ad startup, just enable the service

```
sudo systemctl enable <your-app-name>
```

At the following [link](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) you can find more info to bend the above file to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the package `runit` or `daemontools`, which are very similar.  These are rock-solid tools that allow you to run processes continuously and restart them automatically.

This software starts from your inittab or rc scripts and you configure `runit` or `daemontools` to start and monitor your processes.

You have fine grained control over all of the processes, logging is builtin, and, because these packages start your processes *and* wait for them, will restart dead processes automatically.  It also monitors for quick restarts and throttles back in that case, according to parameters that you can optionally set.

One of the other of these two packages are probably available from a repository for your OS (you didn't mention which one).  Both are available in Debian and Ubunut repositories and I know there's a repo for CentOS.

Here's a page that discusses these two options and others:
http://www.skarnet.org/software/s6/why.html